# Modifying List elements in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, element

Is it possible to update/modify the list elements/items in a loop. Here I have to modify items of `t`

```
n_wk=[1,2,3,2,3,4,2,3]
t=['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a']

for i in range(len(n_wk)):
    if i==0:
        continue
    if n_wk[i]<n_wk[i-1]:
        if t[i]=='a':
            t[i]='b'
        elif t[i]=='b':
            t[i]='c'
    if n_wk[i]>n_wk[i-1]:
       t[i]=t[i-1]
```

I was expecting output `t = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']`. But, the output is coming out to be `t=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']`. Seems like `list t` is not getting updated in the loop.

Can we not update item/elements of the list in a loop?

Comment: Clearly `t` is updated in the loop, since you replaced `a` values with `b` values. Your expectation of when the `elif` matches is incorrect.

Comment: Use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) and make a new list instead. Looping by index is unpythonic - slow, hard to read and inflexible.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of print `t[i]` in the `if n_wk[i]<n_wk[i-1]:` at `i=5` be `'b'`. But, I checked it. It's coming out as `'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list `t` is indeed getting modified:

```
# t before loop
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
# t after loop
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

However, a slight change in your code will give you the result you are looking for:

```py
for i in range(len(n_wk)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    if n_wk[i] < n_wk[i-1]:
        if t[i-1] == 'a': #changed from t[i]
            t[i] = 'b'
        elif t[i-1] == 'b': #changed from t[i]
            t[i] = 'c'
    if n_wk[i] > n_wk[i-1]:
       t[i] = t[i-1]

print(t)
# ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that does not loop using indexes and does not require `t` to be initialized with `'a'`s to begin with:

```
n_wk = [1,2,3,2,3,4,2,3]
t = []

n_prev = 0
t_prev = 'a'

for n in n_wk:
    t_new = t_prev
    if n < n_prev:
        if t_prev == 'a':
            t_new = 'b'
        elif t_prev == 'b':
            t_new = 'c'
    t.append(t_new)
    n_prev = n
    t_prev = t_new

print(t)
```